# Making multilevel nested json from csv for a treemap

Tags: python, json, d3.js, nested

I am making a treemap from a template. The `json` needed to run it is nested but also has information about the group level. I'm trying to figure out how to make the `json` from  a `csv`. I've looked up d3.nest but that doesn't give you information at the group level, all the information is kept down with the leaves.

The new data is also more complicated (has 8 levels and not all groups have children), so looking for a solution that allows me to recursively go through the data and take any format of nesting. [See the csv data](https://github.com/henryjameslau/nested-json-maker/blob/master/Nesting.csv)

I've also thought about using python to tackle the problem, but I'm less experienced with python.

Here's an example of the json format or here for the [full file](https://github.com/henryjameslau/nested-json-maker/blob/master/treemap/treemap/tree_imp.json).

Any pointers or strategies greatly appreciated.

```
{"code":"c0", "desc":"Total", "class":"", "vals":[590486, 590486, 0, 0], "level":"0", "group":"", "children":[
{"code":"c1", "desc":"EU", "class":"c1", "vals":[318029, 318029, 0, 0], "level":"1", "group":"c1", "children":[{"code":"c1_27", "desc":"Sweden", "class":"c1", "vals":[8411, 8411, 0, 0], "level":"2", "group":"c1","children":[
  {"code":"c1_27_1","desc":"angermanland","vals":[100,100,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_2","desc":"blekinge","vals":[200,200,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_3","desc":"bohuslan","vals":[300,300,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_4","desc":"dalarna","vals":[150,150,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_5","desc":"dalsland","vals":[160,160,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_6","desc":"gotland","vals":[107,107,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_7","desc":"gastrikland","vals":[800,800,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_8","desc":"halland","vals":[900,900,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_9","desc":"hasingland","vals":[1100,1100,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_10","desc":"harjedalen","vals":[2100,2100,0,0]},
  {"code":"c1_27_11","desc":"jamtland","vals":[1300,1300,0,0]}

  ]}
]},
{"code":"c2", "desc":"European Free Trade Association", "class":"c2", "vals":[29492, 29492, 0, 0], "level":"1", "group":"c2", "children":[
{"code":"c2_1", "desc":"Iceland", "class":"c2", "vals":[837, 837, 0, 0], "level":"2", "group":"c2"},
{"code":"c2_2", "desc":"Norway", "class":"c2", "vals":[14885, 14885, 0, 0], "level":"2", "group":"c2"},
{"code":"c2_3", "desc":"Switzerland", "class":"c2", "vals":[13730, 13730, 0, 0], "level":"2", "group":"c2"}
]}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full credit goes to [@oskarhane](https://twitter.com/oskarhane).

Posting [the answer here from his blog](http://%20http://oskarhane.com/create-a-nested-array-recursively-in-javascript/)

Starting with data like

```
[
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
    {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1},
    {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3},
    {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
    {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
    {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3},
    {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
]
```

and aiming for

```
[
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
            {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [
                {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
                {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4}
            ]},
            {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3}
        ]}
    ]},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
    ]}
]
```

He uses this function

```
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var out = []
    for(var i in arr) {
        if(arr[i].parent == parent) {
            var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

            if(children.length) {
                arr[i].children = children
            }
            out.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

I had to restructure my data slighty and include a parent id but this did exactly what I needed.